# What database, cache or storage solution to use for large (~80GB) files?

Tags: database, cloud-storage, caching

### Context

I have a bunch of image-like files that I need to store, and then retrieve and keep in memory as various calculations (only read operations) are performed on them. Imagine a library where you take out a book and read it thoroughly over and over, then put it back.

- These files can be anywhere from ~200MB to ~80GB.
- They will be accessed by multiple Django workers (Gunicorn).
- Will be hosted on a cloud platform.
- I will be constantly adding new files, starting with about 10 of them, and potentially adding hundreds each 1-6 months in the upcoming years.
- The initial "load" can take its time to find the file (5-7 seconds until the frontend shows it is fine), but subsequent accesses have to be instantaneous (thus the "keeping in memory" part).
- No queries needed for their contents.
- I have unique identifiers for them, so a key-value solution is very plausible.
- I am running my project in Docker containers, so this service could be in its own container.

### What I've tried

Right now I have those files in a simple filesystem that looks like this:

```
dir1
  subdirA
    file_one.tiff
    file_two.tiff
  subdirB
    file_one.tiff
    file_three.tiff
dir2
  subdirA
    file_one.tiff
```

For development purposes, I have my own simple LFU "cache" that keeps the most accessed files in memory, and works great as long as there are no multiple workers (because, as you have probably guessed, when having multiple workers the amount of cached files in memory gets scaled as well).

A file would get retrieved something like this:

```
file = my_cache.get('dir1/subdirA/file_two.tiff')  # Can take some seconds, no problem

# These should be instantaneous, many of them a second.
# Only read operations.
file.do_calc_1()
file.do_calc_2()
file.do_calc_3()
# (etc.)

file2 = my_cache.get('dir2/subdirA/file_one.tiff')  # Previous file might get discarded from "cache"
```

- I've looked at Redis, but it seems that it's only advisable for smaller-sized data.
- I started looking at HDFS but it's not clear whether it would be a good solution for such a simple problem.
- Maybe I start storing everything in S3? But then, how quickly will those 80GB files be accessed compared to if they existed in the same machine? Is that even scalable? So far, I have ~1-2GB files and they load very quickly when being on the same machine.
- Should I build a totally different API and service to host those files, or can they be reached by the Django app and then returned by it?
- I could create a new Docker container with only that service, but how will authentication and requests work?

As you can see, I'm a bit lost on this. Thank you for the replies.